# datum hash of bytes is different between cardano-serialization-lib and cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli

I am having trouble using cardano-serialization-lib. I am trying to calculate the datum hash from bytes using this library:

```
var myBytes = Buffer.from(
    'b1566319045054327346e0043eed1af00eec2a63d9536f65087ca1c8'
  );
  const dtHash = hash_plutus_data(PlutusData.new_bytes(myBytes));
```

which gives me `a4c44696aa4ed831f3a1c0b86e407a8c092cf680e61ed23f0e47a15b73d59c79`
but when I tried to do it through cli with `cardano-cli transaction hash-script-data --script-data-file $datumFile`
where `datumFile` is

```
{
    "bytes": "b1566319045054327346e0043eed1af00eec2a63d9536f65087ca1"
}
```

I got `edc92947d6f09957c3fe31c10478e6eeee7fdaec1e2cc7439633325cd9bcf13f` instead

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is a known bug which the devs are aiming to fix in the next hard fork. You can see the discussion here: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/227

Does your transaction work when you submit it? If it doesn't, you should get a relevant error related to the datum which you can use to fix your transaction body.